# How the toolbox works after triggering in arcgis pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, .net, toolbox, arcgis-pro-sdk

I wrote an add-in in ArcGIS Pro, when a button is clicked into a button, I go and trigger the toolbox, that is, a .pyt file is triggered and the toolbox comes directly, there is no problem until here, but there is a gp problem, a gui screen opens, goes to the location but does not show it, then it does the operation when I close the opened screen. the codes are as follows.

How can I solve the problem?

```
public async void ToolBoxPython(string name)
        {

            string installPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string toolboxPath = Path.Combine(installPath, $@"PythonToolBoxes\{name}\{name}.pyt\Tool");
            //Geoprocessing.OpenToolDialog(toolboxPath, null);
            var gp_result = await Geoprocessing.ExecuteToolAsync(toolboxPath, null);

        }
```

When I say OpenTooDialog the code works fine, but to say Run I have to go and press the button myself

I am using ArcGIS Pro version 3.1

Comment: You don't appear to be providing the parameters for the python tool that you would normally enter if running the tool manually?

Comment: In fact, when the toolbox is opened, it does not come to a paramtere, when I say run there, I open a gui screen and it works according to the data from there. When I run it directly, the processes do not work, my problem starts here. I found an interface called IGpResult but I could not adapt that code to the dam